# Can I disable auto increment of WordPress Posts Database to utilize previously deleted records?

Tags: php, posts, database, phpmyadmin

When I delete a record field of WordPress posts database such as Post, Image, Page, etc. and add new item then it will add in a fresh record field due to auto increment function.

But I would like to firstly utilize deleted records then enter new data in new record field.

Is it okay to disable auto increment from that database table?

Comment: No it’s not ok. You’ll break your site. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to hack the core? You can always create your own table. Checkout the `$wpdb` class.

Comment: That will not "utilize" anything, but break everything. Why? Save disk space? Let the database mange itself (InnoDB tables) or optimize MyISAM tables.